# How to extract field value from nested SOQL query inside APEX

Tags: apex, soql

If case is updated I would like to send email to all contacts for the account associated with that case.

I am getting list of contacts in map and then looping through the map keyset and then looping through list to send email. I would like to avoid "For" loop for list to make it efficient

```
map<case, list<string>> m = new map<case, list<string>>();
list<string> conList= new list<string>();
for(account a :[select Id, Name, (select Id, AccountId, email from Contacts), (select Id, CaseNumber, AccountId, Account.Name, subject from Cases), Type from Account]){
    for(case cs:a.Cases){
        \\Here below I would like to have a list of all emails related to Case for that account
        conList.addall(a.Contacts);
        m.put(cs,conList);
    }
    conList = new List<string>();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of query is likely to run into governor limits as you are querying every Account and then every Contact and Case related to those Accounts. So if this is code that will remain in use it will break when the data volumes rise so requires significant rethinking.

Assuming this is once-off code in an org with only a few thousand rows in total, and looking at this [ERD](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_support.htm?search_text=erd), I suggest you query the `Case`. In that query you can also retrieve the `Case`s parent `Contact` and that `Contact`'s parent `Account` as you can go 5 levels up the parent hierarchy. This approach avoids any nasty code to try to relate the `Case` to the right `Contact`.

Comment: Thanks Keith. I will give it a try other way.